# How can I deploy a CA Certificate on several machines through network

Tags: security, certificate, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to deploy a CA's X509 certificate on several client machine's (Windows) in a Intranet environment?

Answer (score 2):

Look into Active Directory. Using group policy, you can deploy certificates to computers and servers (Windows) joined to a domain.

Here is an excerpt from [Microsoft: Distribute Certificates to Client Computers by Using Group Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy)

> To distribute certificates to client computers by using Group Policy
> On a domain controller in the forest of the account partner
> organization, start the Group Policy Management snap-in.
>
> Find an existing Group Policy Object (GPO) or create a new GPO to
> contain the certificate settings. Ensure that the GPO is associated
> with the domain, site, or organizational unit (OU) where the
> appropriate user and computer accounts reside.
>
> Right-click the GPO, and then click Edit.
>
> In the console tree, open Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows
> Settings\Security Settings\Public Key Policies, right-click Trusted
> Root Certification Authorities, and then click Import.
>
> On the Welcome to the Certificate Import Wizard page, click Next.
>
> On the File to Import page, type the path to the appropriate
> certificate files (for example, \fs1\c$\fs1.cer), and then click
> Next.
>
> On the Certificate Store page, click Place all certificates in the
> following store, and then click Next.
>
> On the Completing the Certificate Import Wizard page, verify that the
> information you provided is accurate, and then click Finish.
>
> Repeat steps 2 through 6 to add additional certificates for each of
> the federation servers in the farm.

If you don't want computers joined to a domain, look into doing it through PowerShell or Ansible.

Comment: Thanks, I think Active Directory will do the trick, it's really annoying people having to trust it's own company manually.

Comment: Be sure to mark this as the answer if this answer helped you.